# Search Filter moves to tab fragments

Tags: android, search, tabs

I am working on an Activity which is a search page. It contains some values with edittext and spinner. After giving the values and clicking on search button it moves to tab fragments, there contains search results divided by three tabs (By date, By price, By city). I just tested to do on date first but it is not displaying. Please help me on this.

Search Page:

```
public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {    
    EditText name,to,from;
    Spinner cscope,strainer,sinstitute,scity,scountry,cstype,sgender,sdisable,sprice;
    String[] able={"Yes","No"};
    String[] sex={"Male only","Female only","Both Male and Female"};
    String[] price={"Free","1900S.R","1500S.R"};
    String[] city={"Riyadh"};
    Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_csname);
        cscope= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_scope);
        strainer= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_trainerName);
        sinstitute= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_instName);
        scity= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_city);
        scountry= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_country);
        cstype= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_ctype);
        sgender= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_gender);
        sdisable= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_disabled);
        sprice= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_price);
        search= (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchNow);

        ArrayAdapter<String> gen=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sex);
        gen.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sgender.setAdapter(gen);

        ArrayAdapter<String> disableness=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,able);
        disableness.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sdisable.setAdapter(disableness);

        ArrayAdapter<String> pricess=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,price);
        pricess.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sprice.setAdapter(pricess);

        ArrayAdapter<String> cities=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,city);            cities.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        scity.setAdapter(cities);

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String sname=name.getText().toString();
                final String seprice=sprice.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String secity=scity.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String sedate=from.getText().toString();
                Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchResults.class);
                s.putExtra("csname",sname);
                s.putExtra("csprice",seprice);
                s.putExtra("cscity",secity);
                s.putExtra("csdate",sedate);
                startActivity(s);
            }
        });    
    }

    public void selectToDate(View view){
        DialogFragment tofrag=new SelectTodateFragment();
        tofrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Date Picker");
    }
    public void poptoDate(int date,int month,int year){

        to= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_to);
        assert to != null;
        to.setText(date+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class SelectTodateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{    
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final Calendar tocal=Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy=tocal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm=tocal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd=tocal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
           return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);

        }
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int mm, int dd) {
            poptoDate(year, mm+1, dd);
        }    
    }

    public void selectFromDate(View view){
        DialogFragment newfrag=new SelectFromdateFragment();
        newfrag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Date Picker");
    }

    public void popDate(int date,int month,int year){
        from= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_from);
        assert from != null;
        from.setText(date+"/"+month+"/"+year);    
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class SelectFromdateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);    
        }
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int mm, int dd) {
            popDate(year, mm+1, dd);
        }
    }
}
```

Search Results Page:

```
public class SearchResults extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private TabLayout tabs;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    private SearchPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.search_pager);

        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("By Price"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("By Date"));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("By City"));
        tabs.setTabGravity(tabs.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabs.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        pager = new SearchPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pager);

        Intent h=getIntent();
        String cname=h.getStringExtra("csname");
        String byprice=h.getStringExtra("csprice");
        String bydate=h.getStringExtra("csdate");
        String bycity=h.getStringExtra("cscity");
        bundle.putString("coname",cname);
        bundle.putString("coprice",byprice);
        bundle.putString("codate",bydate);
        bundle.putString("cocity",bycity);
        pager.getData(bundle);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));

        tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {    

    }    
}
```

Search pagerAdapter:

```
public class SearchPager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int tabCount;
    private Bundle args=new Bundle();

    public SearchPager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = tabCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {   
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment tab1 = new SearchPrice();
                getData(args);
                tab1.setArguments(args);
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment tab2 = new SearchDate();
                getData(args);
                tab2.setArguments(args);
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Fragment tab3 = new SearchCity();
                getData(args);
                tab3.setArguments(args);
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }

    public void getData(Bundle bundle) {
        this.args=bundle;
    }
}
```

Search BYPrice:

```
public class SearchPrice extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ProgressDialog mprogress;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    private SpriceAdapter adapter;
    TextView id;
    Handler mHandler;
    static String sname;
    static String sprice;

    public SearchPrice() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_price, container, false);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        id = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.copriceId);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchPriceList);

        adapter = new SpriceAdapter(getActivity(), alist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

        if (getArguments() != null) {

            sname = this.getArguments().getString("coname");
            sprice = this.getArguments().getString("coprice");
        }
        final String turl = "http://adoxsolutions.in/numuww/services/courses";

        new ByPrice(this).execute(turl);
        return rootView;
    }

    private class ByPrice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;    

        public ByPrice(SearchPrice activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.getContext());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... turl) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(turl[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connect.setRequestMethod("POST");

                System.out.println("Response Code:" + connect.getResponseCode());
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(response);
                Log.d("VALUE:", response);

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsArray = obj.optJSONArray("Course");
                for (int k = 0; k < jsArray.length(); k++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jsArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    final String cid = jobj.getString("id");
                    final String cn = jobj.getString("course");
                    final String dt = jobj.getString("date");
                    map.put("id", cid);
                    map.put("course", cn);
                    map.put("date", dt);
                    map.put("trainer", jobj.getString("trainer"));
                    map.put("country", jobj.getString("country"));
                    map.put("city", jobj.getString("city"));
                    map.put("days", jobj.getString("no_days"));
                    map.put("hours", jobj.getString("tot_hrs"));
                    map.put("img", jobj.getString("img"));
                    alist.add(map);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (cn.equals(sname) || dt.equals(sprice)) {
                                Log.d("Value", cid);
                                id.setText(cid);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }    
    }

    class SpriceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        private Typeface typeface;

        public SpriceAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            context = c;
            MyArr = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MyArr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final String id = MyArr.get(position).get("id");

            if (convertView != null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlist, parent, false);
                TextView cname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchlistName);
                TextView tname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strainerName);
                TextView country = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchcoName);
                TextView city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchciName);
                TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sdateTime);
                TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scourseTime);
                TextView hours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scourseHours);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scphoto);
                String cn = (MyArr.get(position).get("course"));
                String tn = (MyArr.get(position).get("trainer"));
                String co = (MyArr.get(position).get("country"));
                String ci = (MyArr.get(position).get("city"));
                String dat = (MyArr.get(position).get("date"));
                String dys = (MyArr.get(position).get("days"));
                String hrs = (MyArr.get(position).get("hours"));
                String c = context.getString(R.string.comma);
                String ob = " ( ";
                String cb = " ) ";
                String h = " Hours";
                String d = " Days";
                String trainerName = tn + c;
                String cdays = dys + d;
                String chrs = ob + hrs + h + cb;

                try {
                    if(hrs != null || !hrs.equals("")) {
                        String h1="0 Hours";
                        String chs=ob + h1 + cb;
                        hours.setText(chs);
                    }else{
                        hours.setText(chrs);
                    }

                    //   image.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(hlist.get(position).get("img")));
                    Glide.with(context).load(MyArr.get(position).get("img")).into(image);

                    cname.setText(cn);
                    tname.setText(trainerName);
                    country.setText(co);
                    city.setText(ci);
                    date.setText(dat);
                    time.setText(cdays);

                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent o=new Intent(context,CourseScreen.class);
                            o.putExtra("id",id);
                            context.startActivity(o);
                        }
                    });
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return convertView;
        }    
    }
}
```

Search ByDate:

```
public class SearchDate extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ProgressDialog mprogress;
    TextView id;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist = new ArrayList<>();
    private SdateAdapter adapter;
    Handler mHandler;
    static String sname;
    static String sdate;

    public SearchDate() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_date, container, false);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        id= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.courseId);
        listView= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchDateList);

        adapter = new SdateAdapter(getActivity(), alist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

        if (getArguments() != null) {

            sname = this.getArguments().getString("coname");
            sdate = this.getArguments().getString("codate");
        }
        final String turl = "http://adoxsolutions.in/numuww/services/courses";

        new ByDate(this).execute(turl);
        return rootView;
    }

    private class ByDate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;


        public ByDate(SearchDate activity)
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.getContext());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... turl) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(turl[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connect.setRequestMethod("POST");

                System.out.println("Response Code:" + connect.getResponseCode());
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(response);
                Log.d("VALUE:", response);

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsArray = obj.optJSONArray("Course");
                for (int k = 0; k < jsArray.length(); k++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jsArray.getJSONObject(k);
                    final String cid=jobj.getString("id");
                    final String cn=jobj.getString("course");
                    final String dt=jobj.getString("date");
                    map.put("id",cid);
                    map.put("course",cn);
                    map.put("date", dt);
                    map.put("trainer", jobj.getString("trainer"));
                    map.put("country", jobj.getString("country"));
                    map.put("city", jobj.getString("city"));
                    map.put("days", jobj.getString("no_days"));
                    map.put("hours", jobj.getString("tot_hrs"));
                    map.put("img", jobj.getString("img"));
                    alist.add(map);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(cn.equals(sname) || dt.equals(sdate) ) {
                                Log.d("Value",cid);
                                id.setText(cid);    
                                }
                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }   

    class SdateAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        private Typeface typeface;

        public SdateAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
            context = c;
            MyArr = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MyArr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final String id = MyArr.get(position).get("id");
            final String dt=MyArr.get(position).get("date");

            if (convertView != null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlist, parent, false);
                TextView cname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchlistName);
                TextView tname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.strainerName);
                TextView country = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchcoName);
                TextView city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchciName);
                TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sdateTime);
                TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scourseTime);
                TextView hours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scourseHours);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scphoto);
                String cn = (MyArr.get(position).get("course"));
                String tn = (MyArr.get(position).get("trainer"));
                String co = (MyArr.get(position).get("country"));
                String ci = (MyArr.get(position).get("city"));
                String dat = (MyArr.get(position).get("date"));
                String dys = (MyArr.get(position).get("days"));
                String hrs = (MyArr.get(position).get("hours"));
                String c = context.getString(R.string.comma);
                String ob = " ( ";
                String cb = " ) ";
                String h = " Hours";
                String d = " Days";
                String trainerName = tn + c;
                String cdays = dys + d;
                String chrs = ob + hrs + h + cb;

                try {
                    if(hrs != null || !hrs.equals("")) {
                        String h1="0 Hours";
                        String chs=ob + h1 + cb;
                        hours.setText(chs);
                    }else{
                        hours.setText(chrs);
                    }

                    //   image.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(hlist.get(position).get("img")));
                    Glide.with(context).load(MyArr.get(position).get("img")).into(image);

                    cname.setText(cn);
                    tname.setText(trainerName);
                    country.setText(co);
                    city.setText(ci);
                    date.setText(dat);
                    time.setText(cdays);

                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent o=new Intent(context,CourseScreen.class);
                            o.putExtra("id",id);
                            context.startActivity(o);
                        }
                    });
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Same as Search ByCity:

Comment: You're showing 5 fairly large code blocks here. You should really just do your own debugging to narrow it down to only the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue. See [How to create an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - with emphasis on the *minimal*.

Comment: Sorry... I just added all codes which the activity moves to tabs for understanding what i am doing in my codes. Please check search page and search results. Then By Date page. I am getting "course name" and "date" values from search page to search results.